# % match won't jump over -> in PHP

Tags: delimiter-matching, filetype-php

I've noticed that when **editing a PHP file** (`.php`) and positioning the cursor **after an unmatched opening `<` bracket** and **before `->` and a different opening bracket e.g. `(`**, the `%` motion jumps to the preceding `<` bracket instead of the following `)` bracket.

In the following example I start at the position `1` and after pressing `%` I end up at `2` because it's trying to match the `>` bracket `A` backwards instead of the bracket `B` forward.

```
<?php $foo->bar($baz);
^     ^    ^   ^
2     1    A   B
```

If I match the opening `<` before the starting position, it just stays in place, because it's unable to find the match for the `>` character from the `->` syntax.

I've tried the same in a C and C++ file (`.c` and `.cpp`) and it correctly recognizes the `->` operator as a whole, so in the following example I get from `1` to `2` as I would expect.

```
a < b; foo->bar(baz);
       ^           ^
       1           2
```

I've tried this in a clean vim 8.2 with no custom setup or plugins, so I assume this is the default behavior for these languages.

**Is there a way to set up the PHP behavior to mimic the one in C and C++ files?**

*I imagine this is just one very specific symptom of a greater issue of recognizing matched angle brackets in languages that do care about their matches while allowing them to be unmatched in some cases. It seems like the angle brackets in C++ are not being considered at all for `%` matches (e.g. in templates). For PHP, i guess it's considered because of the HTML outside of the `<?php ?>` tags, but I think I'd be OK with a solution that sacrifices the angle bracket matching in favor of being able to jump over the `->` token.*

*I normally use neovim with tree sitter and matchit plugins. Could some configuration of these or other plugins help with this and potentially other related issues?*

Comment: Compare the output of `:set isk?` in `foo.php` and in `bar.cpp`, then head over to `:help 'iskeyword'`.

Comment: @romainl, they're exactly the same `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`